# Text message "reverser"

Tags: python, beginner, strings, python-3.x

I decided to step out of my comfort zone (Java) and try out Python. I wrote a very simple reverser.py and want it to be reviewed.

```
"""
This python script basically takes a string and reverses it.

This python script can be used as a command line script as well as a separate
module.
"""
import sys


def reverse(message):
    """
    This function takes a string and reverses it, so as to somewhat obfuscate
     it.

    :param message: The unencrypted text message to be reversed.
    """
    text = ''
    for character in message:
        text = character + text
    return text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    numberOfArgs = len(sys.argv)

    message = ''
    if numberOfArgs == 1:  # i.e. the program name only
        message = input('Please enter the text to be encrypted : ')
    elif numberOfArgs == 2:
        message = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        print('Incorrect number of arguments : %d\n' % numberOfArgs)
        print('Usage: python3 reverseCipher [unencrypted string]')
        exit(2)  # '2' stands for command-line syntax errors in unix

    print(reverse(message))
```

Examples in the terminal:

```
$ python3 reverser.py

Please enter the text to be encrypted : I understand that text manipulation in python is quite easy.
.ysae etiuq si nohtyp ni noitalupinam txet taht dnatsrednu I


$ python3 reverser.py "I am just starting out with python"

nohtyp htiw tuo gnitrats tsuj ma I
```

It would be great if I would be advised about:

1. Code style and idioms
2. The required mindset (for I have one for Java)
3. Anything that can help me learn the language

Comment: See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/102052/reversing-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is going to be a short answer, but did you know Python has such a feature in-built?

```
text = "I'm a stringy!"
print(text[::-1])
```

Above would replace your `reverse` method and is the most Pythonic way to solve this.

This is called [extended slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) and has been added since Python 2.3. Slicing is a very easy to use method when handling array-like data.

The following illustrates how slicing and extended slicing can be used, executed in the interactive Python IDE:

```
In [1]: text = "I'm a stringy!"

In [2]: print(text)
I'm a stringy!

In [3]: print(text[:-1])
I'm a stringy

In [4]: print(text[::-1])
!ygnirts a m'I

In [5]: print(text[:4:-1])

In [6]: print((text:4:-1] + text[:3:5])[::-1])
I stringy!

In [7]: print(text[::-1][::-1][::-1])
!ygnirts a m'I
```

[As picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvQhZ.png)

Comment: also useful is `''.join(reversed(text))`, but in this case reverse-stepping is great.

Answer (score 13):

I guess you might have heard of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is *the style guideline* for Python. Contrary to a lot of other programming languages, this style guideline is actually used a lot, and is the main standard for coding in Python.

Your code looks clean, and I like that you've commented using docstrings moth the module/file and the function. Mast does have a point that you can accomplish the same using `message[::-1]`, but part of going into a new language is learning what the language can offer in standard libraries.

Do look into using [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.3.html?highlight=slice#extended-slices)'ing, which is extremely powerful and useful.  A challenge for you is to resolve [Project Euler #13: Large sum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/110527/78136) using Python and sliceing. I think you'll get some pleasant surprises related to string vs number handling, and handling of large numbers as well.

Two other comments related to style issues:

- *Use `snake_case` for variable and function naming* – That is use `number_of_arguments` instead of `numberOfArgs`
- *Look into using format for string formatting* – The `%` is scheduled for depreceation, and you should rather use `print('Incorrect number of arguments: {}'.format(number_of_arguments))`. For more on this see [Format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec), on that page there is also useful examples and syntax for how to pretty print using format.